# Can I execute a command in sub folder in makefile

Tags: c, makefile

My project folders look like this

```
Makefile
/src
  /flash
    build.xml
  /blabla
    ...
```

I wrote a Makefile like this

```
flash: src/flash/bin-debug/App.swf

src/flash/bin-debug/App.swf:
    cd src/flash
    ant
```

When I execute `make flash`, I get the following message:

```
cd src/flash/
ant
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
make: *** [src/flash/bin-debug/App.swf] Error 1
```

How can I execute `ant` in `src/flash`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by aix, you must write `cd src/flash; ant` on a single line.

As you haven't specified any dependencies for the App.swf target, make cannot rebuild when they change. You could add them. The problem is that you don't want to duplicate the work you are already doing with ant.

With GNU Make the solution is to use a [phony target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets). It is a type of target that is not interpreted as a file name and whose commands will be executed every time the target is built.

This looks something like this:

```
.PHONY: flash

flash:
    cd src/flash; ant
```

Typing `make flash` repeatedly will invoke ant every time.

Answer (score 7):

`make` [creates a new subshell for each line](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_5.html#SEC46). Try:

```
src/flash/bin-debug/App.swf:
    cd src/flash; ant
```

Otherwise the two commands are executed in two separate subshells. The effect of the `cd` is lost when the first subshell terminates.

Comment: Thanks. it works. but it seams if the App.swf once created it will never execute this task any more. are there anyway to force it execute every time or check if any files in `/src/flash/src/**/*`, `/src/flash/res/**/*` changes